# CS50 Blur compiles but filter doesn't get applied on the picture

Tags: c, filter, cs50, pixel, blur

I'm brand new to programming and I'm going through the CS50 course. Got stuck on Blur problem for weeks. The code compiles but the image doesn't change to blur.  [These are the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG5X4.png)

I don't really understand those numbers shown in the error message and what they mean, looks like the value of the pixel is not what it's supposed to be. I found a similar question on the platform but the code was written different than mine and the answer to it did not help me :( Thank you for your time!

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
// make copy of file
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
    {
        temp[row][column] = image[row][column];
    }
}
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
        {
           int totalRed, totalGreen, totalBlue;
            totalRed = totalGreen = totalBlue = 0;
            float counter = 0.00;


            //find neighbour pixels

            for ( int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
                {
                  int currentRow = height + row;
                  int currentColumn = width + column;

                    //exclude invalid pixels

                      if (currentRow < 0 || currentRow > (height - 1) || currentColumn < 0 || currentColumn > (width - 1))
                       {
                        continue;
                       }

                       // adding the total value of the valid neighbouring pixels
                       totalRed += image[currentRow][currentColumn].rgbtRed;
                       totalGreen += image[currentRow][currentColumn].rgbtGreen;
                       totalBlue += image[currentRow][currentColumn].rgbtBlue;

                       counter++;

                }
                //calculate average of sorrounding pixels
          temp[height][width].rgbtRed = round(totalRed / counter);
          temp[height][width].rgbtGreen= round(totalGreen / counter);
          temp[height][width].rgbtBlue= round(totalBlue / counter);

            }
        }
    }
 // copy temp values in original file
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
        {
            image[row][column].rgbtRed = temp[row][column].rgbtRed;
            image[row][column].rgbtGreen = temp[row][column].rgbtGreen;
            image[row][column].rgbtBlue = temp[row][column].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste any and all text *as text* into your questions. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my apologies, I edited the post and added the code as text. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is with these lines:

```
for ( int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
    {
        int currentRow = height + row;
        int currentColumn = width + column;
```

Here you set `currentRow` to the *full height* of the image, and then add the current row index. It will *always* be outside of the image. Same with the column.

What I'm *guessing* you're supposed to do is:

```
int currentRow = row + i;
int currentColumn = column + j;
```

This will get the pixels around the current row and column and use for the blurring.

Comment: Thank you I tried this but it gives me the same error :(

Comment: @wakulovszki  Seems it's time to go into your [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values to see what's really happening.